# What is the difference between BEGIN followed by IF and IF followed by BEGIN

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am new to PL/SQL. What is the difference between the below two flows?

1. BEGIN followed by IF

   ```
    BEGIN
    IF flag= 1  THEN
         FOR SOME_REC(id)
         LOOP

         END LOOP;
    END IF;
    END
   ```
2. IF followed by BEGIN

   ```
    IF flag= 1  THEN
   BEGIN
         FOR SOME_REC(id)
         LOOP

         END LOOP;
   END
   END IF;
   ```

Comment: Actually, the BEGIN and END in the second example are not required.

Comment: Is the first example a complete executable block, or is it part of a larger procedure/function/method?

Answer (score 2):

By its design PL/SQL is a block structured language with each block consisting of 4 components:

1. Declaration Section - optional:; DECLARE or Named Block (Function, Procedure, ...)
2. Execution Section   - required: BEGIN
3. Exception Section   - optional: EXCEPTION
4. End Statement       - required: END

As @Mr.AF indicates each block defines the SCOPE of variables. Further these blocks can be nested. So a variable declared in an outer block is visible within that block and all blocks nested within. Subject to the rule that closest declaration wins and items declared in an nested bloc are not visible in outer blocks. See [GURU99](https://www.guru99.com/introduction-pl-sql.html) for fuller description. Try the following.

```
declare 
   var  varchar2(5) := '12345';
begin
   dbms_output.put_line ( 'Outer block has variable ''var'' and has a length of ' 
                        || to_char(length(var)) || ' and value of ' || var);

   declare -- start nested block
      var varchar2(8);
      inner_only varchar2(8) := 'ShotTerm'; 
   begin
      var := '12345678';
      dbms_output.put_line ( 'Inner block has variable ''var'' and has a length of ' 
                           || to_char(length(var)) || ' and value of ' || var  
                           || ' and also variable inner_only with value ' || inner_only);
   end ; -- end nested block 

   dbms_output.put_line ( 'Outer block variable ''var'' still has a length of ' 
                         || to_char(length(var)) || ' and value of ' || var);
   
   -- uncomment below to see difference                         
   -- dbms_output_put_line('A reference to ' || inner_only || ' does not work; gives compile error');                           
end ; --outer block
```

For your specific scenarios #1 the IF and LOOP are being run in an outer (or only) block. While #2 the IF is run in the outer block while the loop runs in an inner block. Note: #2 **must** have a prior BEGIN and the END IF **must** be followed by an END - without them you will get a compile syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

`BEGIN ... END` keywords implies starting point and end point of a code block like `{ }` and compiler will validate local references (locality of references) within the block.otherwise, unexpected results may be happened.

Answer (score 1):

The way you put it, without any further explanation of what problem you are trying to solve (if any), then there's no much difference in those two pieces of code. Both will do what they are supposed to do.

However, I'd like to say something about the 3rd case you never mentioned: `BEGIN-EXCEPTION-END` block **within** the loop, which does make the difference.

```
IF flag = 1 THEN
   FOR SOME_REC(id) LOOP
     BEGIN
       do_something_here;
     EXCEPTION
       when some exception then
         handle it
     END;
   END LOOP;
END IF;
```

What would be its purpose? In both of your examples, if any exception occurs *within* the loop, processing will be stopped and the procedure will terminate.

But, if there's an *inner* `begin-exception-end` block, it lets you capture an error within the loop, handle it the way you find the most appropriate (if there's nothing better, just log the error) and **move on** to the next loop cycle.

Doing so, you'll be able to process all records returned by the cursor. Some of them might fail, that's true, but you'll be able to proceed with the execution.

Here's an example based on Scott's `EMP` table; I'll try to divide `SAL` and `NVL(COMM, 0)` which will result in *divide by zero* error in some cases.

```
SQL> select ename, sal, nvl(comm, 0) comm from emp where deptno = 30 order by ename;

ENAME             SAL       COMM
---------- ---------- ----------
ALLEN            1600        300
BLAKE            2850          0     --> 2850/0 --> error
JAMES             950          0     --> error
MARTIN           1250       1400
TURNER           1500          0     --> error
WARD             1250        500

6 rows selected.
```

Code, as you wrote it:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> declare
  2    l_divided number;
  3  begin
  4    for cur_r in (select ename, sal, nvl(comm, 0) comm
  5                  from emp
  6                  where deptno = 30
  7                  order by ename
  8                 )
  9    loop
 10      l_divided := round(cur_r.sal / cur_r.comm);
 11      dbms_output.put_line(cur_r.ename ||': ' || l_divided);
 12    end loop;
 13  end;
 14  /
ALLEN: 5
declare
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01476: divisor is equal to zero
ORA-06512: at line 10


SQL>
```

See? Only the first one, Allen, had valid data. The rest of them weren't even calculated, as soon as the first error appeared.

But, if you rewrite it as I suggested, then all of them are processed:

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_divided number;
  3  begin
  4    for cur_r in (select ename, sal, nvl(comm, 0) comm
  5                  from emp
  6                  where deptno = 30
  7                  order by ename
  8                 )
  9    loop
 10      begin
 11        l_divided := round(cur_r.sal / cur_r.comm);
 12        dbms_output.put_line(cur_r.ename ||': ' || l_divided);
 13      exception
 14        when zero_divide then
 15          dbms_output.put_line(cur_r.ename ||': COMM is equal to zero');
 16      end;
 17    end loop;
 18  end;
 19  /
ALLEN: 5
BLAKE: COMM is equal to zero
JAMES: COMM is equal to zero
MARTIN: 1
TURNER: COMM is equal to zero
WARD: 3

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

---

See if the above makes any sense in what you asked.